# Rechecking something in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, pagination

Basically I have a jQuery function that checks if the user is near the bottom of the page and loads more stuff. When the document loads this is ran, to check.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var number = 5;
    offset = 0;

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 10) {

            $(".empty-div").append().load('<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/ajax.php?offset='+offset+number, function() {

                    var offset = offset+number;             

                    setTimeout(function(){ console.log('after', $(document).height()); }, 0);
                    setTimeout(function(){ console.log('after', $(window).height()); }, 0);



            });     

        }

    });

});
</script>
```

H/e whenever I reach the bottom of the page on the second go, it doesn't redo the load function. It does work the first time, by the way. Any ideas how to remedy this? The console stuff is there to recalculate the heights, just in case that's what's causing it.

Comment: it's called infinite scrolling isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you use load() there on $(".empty-div"), this would'nt add more content, it will replace the content(if the response does'nt change, you will see no change)

   It better should be something like

   ```
   $('<div/>').appendTo(".empty-div").load(/*****/)
   ```
2. maybe there also is a problem with the DOCTYPE. Log

   ```
   $(window).scrollTop(),  $(window).height() and  $(document).height()
   ```

   maybe, it differs between standards - and quirks-mode.

Comment: I'm going to give you the correct answer tick, seeing as your answer led me to research further, and find the answer. So in a roundabout way, you were right. ;)

Answer (score 3):

By doing this:

```
var offset = offset+number;
```

You're creating a *new* local `offset` variable, not updating your original

```
offset = 0;
```

declared before the function, so this: `?offset='+offset+number` is always using `offset` as `0`, since it's never updated.  Just remove the `var`, like this:

```
offset = offset+number;
```

---

For cleanliness, also add a `var` to the original declaration, or use a comma for a multiple declaration, like this:

```
var number = 5, offset = 0;
```

Comment: @Amir - yes, absolutely...I left it unchanged as to better illustrate why it *wasn't* working :)

Comment: Although that was a problem, the main problem is the load function doesn't run again the second time i scroll to the bottom. Adding more content increases the distance to the bottom, and when I scroll past the critical point nothing happens. Any ideas? :(